Converted Model Using TensorFlow.JS Converter Not Working
I was following the TFJS WebML YT Course from Jason Mayes and following along to the TFJS Converter video, here's my notebook:
Google Colab Notebook
Basically it is an exact replica from the video and with a few extra warnings here and there, the model files were generated:
MobileNetV2.zip
On my site, I used TFJS with tf.loadLayersModel('URL OF MODEL.JSON') but an error was given saying an InputLayer should have been passed either a batchInputShape or an inputShape. There is a batch_shape in the model.json though. TFJS is up to date, no clue whats going on.
I am trying to convert a MobileNetV3-Large actually but the same thing happened too and I was left with this (using same notebook as earlier but replacing tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2 with tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Large, but got same results as earlier):
MobileNetV3-Large.zip
Any help appreciated! This is probably just me stupid as I'm learning TF/TFJS and ML in general, so sorry in advance!
